# livereload.Server with Flask causing NotImplementedError in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, livereload, hot-reload

In an attempt to obtain [hot reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56974220) in Python 3.8 on Windows 10, I'm running:

```
from flask import Flask
from livereload import Server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    server = Server(flask_app.wsgi_app)
    server.serve()  # Why NotImplementedError here?
```

But getting a `NotImplementedError` at `server.serve()`. Googling/SO-crawling/... wasn't beneficial.

Why is it happening? how do I fix it?

#### More Info:

Stack trace:

```
Serving on http://127.0.0.1:5500
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/aaa/error/demo.py", line 7, in <module>
    server.serve()  # Why NotImplementedError here?
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\livereload\server.py", line 298, in serve
    self.application(
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\livereload\server.py", line 253, in application
    app.listen(port, address=host)
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 2112, in listen
    server.listen(port, address)
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\aaa\error\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

The library's project: https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload

Comment: Right, that's indeed the same issue, found you a duplicate. Also already reported to livereload at https://github.com/lepture/python-livereload/issues/209

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for all your effort. So no solution for now, I have to find another solution/library (didn't understand the `site.py` W/A, but sounds too hacky)?